# Apply HTML color attribute based on value from server

Tags: jstl

I have an HTML table in which I want to highlight specific rows.
Following is the code snippet:

```
<c:forEach items="${vmnUploadList}" var="vmn"> 
      <tr>
        <td><a  style="color:#0063b1; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none" href="showVmnLeadDetails?vmnid=${vmn.id}">${vmn.id}</a></td>
        <td>${vmn.customerNo}</td>
        <td>${vmn.circle}</td>
        <td>${vmn.callDate}</td>
        <td>${vmn.callStartTime}</td>
        <td>${vmn.callEndTime}</td>
        <td>${vmn.duration}</td>
        <td>${vmn.callStatus}</td>
        <td>${vmn.uploadDate}</td>
        <td>${vmn.recievingNum}</td>
        <td>${leadStatusMap[vmn.leadStatus]}</td>
      </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Now I also get an attribute  `${vmn.highlight} which returns either true or false`.
If the value is true I want to apply bgcolor="red" to the `table row` else no color to be applied.Could anyone suggest How I could acheive this.Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = $("table tr").map(function (index, elem) {

    $(td, this).each(function () {
        var tdvalue = $(this).val()||$(this).text();
        var tdvaluemain=$.trim(tdvalue);     //to remove spaces from td value 
        if(tdvaluemain=="true"){
            $(this).css("color","black"); //change font color if you want 
            $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color","red");
        }




        });
     });
```